# Contains query Spring data

Tags: spring-data

I would like to use the `LIKE` operator in spring data but nothing happens with the query below:

```
  @query("select a.designation from article a,stock s where (a.idArticle=s.article.idArticle and (a.designation LIKE %:x%") 
             public page<Stock> listArticles(@param("x") String designation);
```

I know that I can use findByDesignationContaining, but I have to use query here because I have to join the two tables.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [concat](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_string_fun) JPQL function:

```
...(a.designation LIKE concat('%', :x, '%'))
```

If you need case insensitive 'like' you can use 'upper'/'lower' functions:

```
...(upper(a.designation) LIKE concat('%', upper(:x), '%'))
```