# Spring data different result for same logical expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data repository for building a web application. Where I am using custom queries using `@Query` annotation. When I am using the below query

```
select u from UserAdmin u where (u.firstName like :firstName% or:firstName is null)
```

In this case, If the `:firstName` parameter is `null` then it returns all the records and otherwise it returns only the matching records by the `like` statement. (**This is working as expected**)

```
select u from UserAdmin u where  ( :firstName is null or u.firstName like :firstName% )
```

In this case, query returns all the records if the `:firstName` parameter is `null` and otherwise it returns records only if  `u.firstName = :firstName` condition is true. (In this scenario `Like` statement is not working as expected)

Could anyone explain the reason for this behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use [concat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507282/5380322) function...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like is the limitation of the JDBC driver.

The query will work if your firstName parameter is actually `null` in which you'll get all records in both scenarios.

But when the firstName has a value then the JDBC driver is unable to apply the `%` when binding the parameter to the query in scenario `:firstName is null or u.firstName like :firstName%`.

Looks like it is giving precedence to the first `null` check but I'm not completely sure of the reason.

But why can't you have the `%` applied beforehand rather than in your `@Query`, like using a `StringBuilder firstName` for the query, as in

```
firstName.append('%')
```

and then modifying the Repository query to

```
select u from UserAdmin u where  ( :firstName is null or u.firstName like :firstName )
```

StringBuilder params can be easily bound to `RestControllers` Request params so you won't have any much unnecessary manipulation.

This should help you in achieving the desired result.